# Facebook Payments - Error Code : 1383008 . The app you're using is not responding

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-payments

We're moving from the old facebook payments method (which involved FB credits) to the new local currency system. We're using dynamic pricing.

```
var obj = { 
method: 'pay', 
action: 'purchaseitem', 
product: 'produrl.php', 
quantity: 1, 
}; 

FB.ui(obj, FBCcallback);
```

(Is defining purchaseitem action is "required" or mandatory)

The product url has been scraped and it does give the required results in the debug tool. The callback url is also tested and is working. Yet the error persists. Someone suggested that we leave it over night, that didn't work out either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons why Facebook would consider the server callback to be not responsive is if the server script caused an error. So if you're using PHP and you get this error, check your error log or use Facebook's sample script for testing.

If the sample works, then there's definitely an error in your PHP script.